# How to implement keycloak on a public server / not localhost

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I know it's quite a general question, but I don't know how, where or what to look for.
I am writing my first application and I use keycloak login. Everything works fine on localhost, but I wanted to put it publicly on my computer to test this application with my friends. And here comes the problem. I set a public ip and after typing it in the friends browser, friends enter the page of my application. Unfortunately, after clicking the login button, they get 500 or no connection to the server.

Does the keycloak or my java application need any additional settings or functionality? Where and what should I configure? When to use external ip, computer ip and localhost?

I know it's not a very precise question, but I don't even know what I'm looking for or what to call it. I would be very grateful for any tips, resources and help.

Regards and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application accessing Keycloak from within your LAN? As shown [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker_overview), the Service Provider (your service), the Identity Broker, and the Identity Provider (if applicable) need to be network resolvable by your friend. This might be tricky if it's all within your LAN.

You might want to consider testing in Digital Ocean or Linode. They have free trials you can use for testing, etc.